# How to keep the Chrome debug panel

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code

When I run chrome to debug my Angular App from vscode, I like to open the browser's developer tools in chrome to the Console tab to view the console output in the browser. The problem is that the browser keeps autoselecting the Sources tab as I navigate thru the app - forcing me to constantly have to re-select the Console tab (very annoying). Is there a setting that keeps the Console tab constantly selected?

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out how to fix this problem. Hope it'll be helpful for anyone who comes here in the future.

Right-click the source penal and choose "Move to bottom" and then you could resize the bottom panel size to hide it or just press ESC.

Happy Debugging!

[check this picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SLEm.jpg)